# Difference of DateTime in dart

Tags: date, flutter, dart

I wanted to calculate the date from now and 7 day after in dart.In php,I used this `time() + (DAY_IN_SECONDS * 7)`,how can I get this in dart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.3/dart-core/DateTime-class.html):

```
var now = new DateTime.now();
var sevenDaysFromNow = now.add(new Duration(days: 7));
```